# SQL Server : Conditional Sort with Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting

I am having an issue with a conditional sort in SQL Server. I have a lengthy procedure that in the end produces a list of magazine subscriptions that are up for renewal. This is the basic structure of the end result table:

```
create table #renewals 
(
    product_no              integer NULL,   
    quantity                integer NULL,   
    order_date              datetime NULL,   
    order_no                integer NULL,   
    customer_no             varchar(10) NULL,   
    description             varchar(50) NULL,   
    first_name              varchar(30) NULL,   
    middle_name             varchar(30) NULL,   
    last_name               varchar(30) NULL,   
    salute                  varchar(5) NULL,   
    acct_no                 char(8) NULL, 
    contact_type            varchar(8) NULL,
    contact_no              integer NULL,
    line_item               int,
    edition_code            char(3) NULL
)
```

The issue lies in the multi-level sort that I am trying to accomplish. In the end, I need this data sorted by `edition_code` ASC which is simple enough.

However, some editions have add-on products which then need to be inserted underneath the correct `edition_code`. This is where I am running into a problem. An example of a regular edition code is `002` or `014`. The add-on edition codes are `300`, `302`, etc. If I only sort by `edition_code` then all of the add-on editions get moved to the bottom of the list.

The following is a rundown of the result set:

```
product_no -- This is a different number than edition_code, but same principal
quantity -- self-explanatory
order_date -- self-explanatory
order_no -- For each unique result set, this number is the same
customer_no -- this is unique for each customer and helps to bundle main editions with their add-ons
description -- title of edition
first (through) last_name -- self-explanatory
salute -- self-explanatory
acct_no -- For each result set, this number is the same because all the customers will belong to the same account (think multiple doctors subscribing to a magazine but all work out of the same hospital)
contact_type -- PK
contact_no -- PK
line_item -- line number when entered on order (this does not help with sorting at all)
edition_code -- Unique code for an edition of our product
```

Below is the result I am expecting:

```
Customer_1 | Edition_1
Customer_2 | Edition_1
Customer_2 | Add-On_1
Customer_2 | Add-On_2
Customer_9 | Edition_1
Customer_6 | Edition_2
Customer_5 | Edition_2
Customer_5 | Add-On_2
Customer_3 | Edition_3
```

The closest I can get is by simply sorting by `customer_no` which will put the add-ons with their editions (You cannot order an add-on without ordering the main edition), but this does not sort by main edition code, which is what the overall (main) sort should accomplish.

This is the procedure that produces the result, not sure how it'll help:

```
CREATE TABLE #renewals 
(
    product_no              integer NULL,   
    quantity                integer NULL,   
    order_date              datetime NULL,   
    order_no                integer NULL,   
    customer_no             varchar(10) NULL,   
    description             varchar(50) NULL,   
    first_name              varchar(30) NULL,   
    middle_name             varchar(30) NULL,   
    last_name               varchar(30) NULL,   
    salute                  varchar(5) NULL,   
    acct_no                 char(8) NULL, 
    contact_type        varchar(8) NULL,
    contact_no          integer NULL,
    line_item               int,
    edition_code            char(3) NULL
)

INSERT INTO #renewals 
(
    product_no,   
    quantity,   
    order_date,   
    order_no,   
    customer_no,   
    description,   
    first_name,   
    middle_name,   
    last_name,   
    salute,   
    acct_no, 
    contact_type,
    contact_no ,
    line_item,
    edition_code
)
SELECT
    product.product_no,   
    order_table_1.quantity,   
    order_table_1.order_date,   
    order_table_1.order_no,   
    order_table_1.customer_no,   
    product.description,  
    isnull(customer_table_1.first_name, ''),
    isnull(customer_table_1.middle_name, ''),
    isnull(customer_table_1.last_name, ''),
    isnull(customer_table_1.salute, ''),
    order_table_1.acct_no,
    '',
    -1,
    line_item_no,
    order_table_1.edition_code
FROM order_table_1
LEFT OUTER JOIN product ON order_table_1.edition_code = product.edition_code
LEFT OUTER JOIN customer_table_1 ON order_table_1.customer_no = customer_table_1.customer_no AND order_table_1.acct_no = customer_table_1.acct
WHERE
    (order_table_1.acct_no = @acct) AND  
    (order_table_1.school_year = @school_year) AND
    (order_table_1.edition_code <> '065') AND  
    (order_table_1.status_code in ('E','A','F')) AND  
    (isnull(order_table_1.renewed,'N') <> 'Y')            

UPDATE o 
SET o.first_name = isnull(tc.first_name, ''),
    o.middle_name = isnull(tc.middle_name, ''),
    o.last_name = isnull(tc.last_name, ''),
    o.salute = isnull(tc.salute, ''),
    o.contact_type = tc.contact_type,
    o.contact_no = tc.contact_no
FROM #renewals o, accounts ta, contacts tc
WHERE
    (o.acct_no = ta.acct) AND  
    (ta.acct_type = tc.acct_type) AND  
    (ta.acct_no = tc.acct_no) AND  
    (o.customer_no = tc.customer_no) AND  
    (o.customer_no is not null) AND 
    (o.customer_no <> '') AND 
    (o.customer_no not like '999999999%')

SELECT
    cast(o.product_no as int) as 'product_no', 
    o.quantity,   
    o.order_date,   
    o.order_no,   
    o.customer_no,   
    o.description,   
    o.first_name,   
    o.middle_name,   
    o.last_name,   
    o.salute,   
    o.acct_no, 
    o.contact_type,
    o.contact_no,
    o.line_item,
    o.edition_code
FROM #renewals o
ORDER BY o.edition_code
```

Comment: MS SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

Comment: Some examples of actual queries, or at least of sort expressions, would be helpful.

Comment: @Dave Added the entire SP if you think it'll help

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: In your expected results, how would I distinguish that Add-On-2 is positioned underneath Edition-1 for Customer 2, whereas it should be positioned underneath Edition-2 for Customer 5? I could try and use `order_no`, but can a customer order more than one edition at once?

Comment: The logic you might be looking for is along the lines of `ORDER BY CASE WHEN Product LIKE 'condition' THEN 0 WHEN Product LIKE 'some other condition' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END;`

Comment: Or a better question, how do I distinguish that the add-ons for Customer-2 belong to Edition-1 and not Edition-2?

Comment: @marc_s I did not write the original query

Comment: @OliverFrost An individual customer will only be able to order one main edition, so if they also order add-ons then the add-ons will go with the main edition they ordered.  Good question.

Comment: @OliverFrost I realized that I made a mistake in my expected example results.  These subscriptions are for magazines and are grade level based for teachers.  A teacher will only order one main edition that correlates to the grade they teach, and may add one or two add-on editions if they so desire.

Answer (score 0):

You can't sort what you don't have.  You need a table of `edition_code, addon_code` pairs.  Then join to that table with

```
#renewals.edition_code in (X.edition_code, X.addon_code)
...
order by X.edition_code, X.addon_code
```

I'm making a few assumptions: that the two code sets don't overlap, that edition_code is always less than addon_code, and that you want the addons ordered by their code.  Sometimes in cases like this a third column is required to express the sort order.

Comment: It wouldn't be difficult to create a table with those pairs.  I am not clear however on how to use that new table with the example you posted, could you clarify please?